# Order by in SQL Server does not give me the same result

Tags: sql-server

Why does:

```
ORDER BY mx.Total, o.OrderID, ol.Quantity DESC
```

give a completely different answer than:

```
ORDER BY mx.Total DESC, o.OrderID DESC, ol.Quantity DESC
```

It feels like I missed something in my SQL education...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY clause` structure:

```
   ORDER BY expression [ASC, DESC]

ASC: min value to max value
DESC: max value to min value
```

If not have ASC or DESC, default ASC. And expressions|columns not shared ASC|DESC. It mean:
`Col1, Col2 DESC` **not like** `(Col1, Col2) DESC`

When in ORDER BY have many expressions|columns, first column to first sort (order), then next column sort based on the result sorted first colum, and next...

For example:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
 1     2     3
 2     3     1
 3     4     1
 2     3     4
 1     2     4
 1     4     4
 2     2     3
```

When: ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3, result will:

```
 Col1  Col2  Col3
   1     2     3
   1     2     4
   1     4     4
   2     2     3
   2     3     1     
   2     3     4         
   3     4     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the default order is `ASC` if you don't specify one. So

```
ORDER BY mx.Total, o.OrderID, ol.Quantity DESC
```

is in fact

```
ORDER BY mx.Total ASC, o.OrderID ASC, ol.Quantity DESC
```

You have to specify the order for every column!